# Cumsum for data frame by group

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a data frame with 10 columns, col1,col2,col3...col10. I would like to find the cumsum by year for all columns. With this code, I am able to find the cumsum for only 1 column (col1). Is there a way to find the cumsum for the whole data frame?

```
Data <- Data %>%
group_by(Year) %>%
mutate(col1_cumsum = cumsum(col1))
```

Comment: `Data <- Data %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(across(col1:col10, cumsum))`

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked. I'm quite new to R and am not quite familiar with all functions like "across". Learnt a new function today. Thanks.